# Dynamic year range for Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using Datepicker for selecting the Expiry date. I want my datepicker to have year option as:

1. When we load the datepicker it's year options should start from current year and end at 20 year after current year. It should not show the year before the current year.
   for example: current year = 2017, so datepicker will show year range from 2017 to 2037.
2. When we select an year such as 2037, my date picker should show the year option range of 2027 to 2047

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      minDate: 0,
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

I am able to get the year option starting from current year, and not having the year option before the current year, But my option contain only 10 year after the current year. I need it to be 20 year from current year.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: new Date().getFullYear() + ':+20',
    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {

        if(year !== inst.currentYear) {
            var newYear = year;
            $('#datepicker').datepicker('option', 'yearRange', (newYear-10) + ':' + (newYear + 10));
            $('#datepicker').datepicker('option', 'defaultDate','01/01/' + newYear);

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: i dont want to limit my year range. it will just give year ranging from 2027 to 2047. what if i want to select 2017

Comment: But you asked in the question that when user selects 2037, datepicker should show 2027 to 2047. What do you exactly need?

Comment: yes but, i have to requirement, first when i enter date picker it should show the year range from 2017 to 2037. when i select the any year for ex. click on 2027, again check the range of year option, it will be from 2017 to 2037,click on 2037, again check the range of year option, it will be from 2027 to 2047 and so on...

Comment: I have edited my answer. Check if it does what you want

Comment: thanks man but date picker is selecting different value. actualy 10 year before, please correct, i am new to jquery.

Comment: check now. it should get what you want

Comment: sorry, but this example allows past years lol how is it better then my code?!

Comment: :) and datepicker is also closing on year selection.

Comment: question states to not allow past years so how is it the best answer here?!

Comment: Question and user requirement above states not to show past years when you initialise the datepicker. But after you change the year from dropdown it should show 10 years before and after

Answer (score 1):

Try this example, it wont allow past years:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>

    <script>
        var now = new Date(),
            year_offset = 20,
            start = now.getFullYear(),
            end = now.getFullYear() + year_offset;

        var onChangeMonthYear = function( year, month, inst ) {
            start   = ( year - (year_offset / 2) < now.getFullYear() ) ? now.getFullYear() : year - (year_offset / 2);
            end     = start + year_offset;
            inst.settings.yearRange = parseInt( start ) + ":" + parseInt( end );
        }

        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            minDate: 0,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: start + ":" + end,
            onChangeMonthYear: onChangeMonthYear
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: when i select an year i am not getting year range from 10 year before selected and 10 year after selected. insted i am getting 20 year from the selected year.

Comment: I am sorry. but it is slightly what i want but not correct one. if i select any year i should get 10 year before and ten year after the selected year. such as if i select 2030, the range should be 2020 to 2030

Comment: ok, I got what you need, try again. It took me a while to fix event propagation issue. I havent been using jQuery since a while.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function () {

 $('#datepicker2').datepicker({
     changeMonth: true,
     changeYear: true,
     minDate: 0,
     yearRange: 'c-10:c+20',

 }); });
```

Comment: i dont want to limit my year range.

Comment: it will just give year ranging from 2017 to 2037. what if i want to select 2047

Comment: Your second point is not clear. Can you please clarify it little more.

Comment: i want the default functioning of the date picker. please run the code spinet and see what are the innitial option of year we get. you will find it to be 2017 to 2027. click on 2027, again check the range of year option, it will be from 2017 to 2037,click on 2037, again check the range of year option, it will be from 2027 to 2047 and so on....

Comment: As per my understanding, you need next 20 years in the datepicker when user first time click on it, now let's suppose he selects 2037 now datepicker will show the range from 2027 to 2047. Right?

Comment: yes, this is what i want but next 20 year would be from the current year.